# Fill new pandas df based off values in another df

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, if-statement

I am new here, so please don't be to hard on me! :)

See picture below!

[image: Print screen: df['Datan]]

I am trying to create a new dataframe (`df['New_df']`) based on the values in `df['Datan']` so that `df['New_df']` is equal to `df['Datan']` on the rows where the string `#SRU` appears. If the string is not in `df['Datan']`, I want `df['New_df']` to "keep" the value of the row above (where the `#SRU` string was included).

See below df of what I am trying to do.

```
                                          Datan          New_df
                                 #SRU 1512 7251  #SRU 1512 7251
   #KONTO 1513 "Kundfordringar - delad faktura"  #SRU 1512 7251
                                 #SRU 1513 7251  #SRU 1513 7251
   #KONTO 1519 "Nedskrivning av kundfordringar"  #SRU 1513 7251
                                 #SRU 1519 7251  #SRU 1519 7251
```

I have been trying around with for loops combined with if statements with the apply method in particular but haven't reached a solution as of yet. Not able to find this specific problem in any other threads here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, the combination of [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) & [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
m = df['Datan'].str.contains(r'#SRU')
df['New_df'] = df['Datan'].mask(~m).ffill()
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
                                          Datan          New_df
0                                #SRU 1512 7251  #SRU 1512 7251
1  #KONTO 1513 "Kundfordringar - delad faktura"  #SRU 1512 7251
2                                #SRU 1513 7251  #SRU 1513 7251
3  #KONTO 1519 "Nedskrivning av kundfordringar"  #SRU 1513 7251
4                                #SRU 1519 7251  #SRU 1519 7251
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check `string` match and then use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) to fill `na`

```
df['New_df'] = df.Datan.where(df.Datan.str.contains('#SRU')).ffill()
```

```
df
   Index                                           Datan            New_df
0     95                                 #SRU 1512 7251    #SRU 1512 7251
1     96   #KONTO 1513 "Kundfordringar - delad faktura"    #SRU 1512 7251
2     97                                 #SRU 1513 7251    #SRU 1513 7251
3     98   #KONTO 1519 "Nedskrivning av kundfordringar"    #SRU 1513 7251
4     99                                 #SRU 1519 7251    #SRU 1519 7251
```